# DNS migration to Route53

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have transferred domain name from https://www.onlydomains.com/ to aws Route53. Using name-server,it works most of the time, but sometime it will not be available for some time max 5 min.

I have tried using alias, it works for other domain which I have added alias to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your domain zone still in transfer, you could either use tools like [drill](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=drill&sektion=1)/dig:

```
$ dig your-domain.tld ns
```

This will show the existing nameservers, but the same tool can be used for checking `A` records, example:

```
$ dig your-domain.tld +trace
```

The `+trace` option makes iterative queries to resolve the name being looked up. it helps to see what servers still using your old DNS provider.

Also, could be an issue with your own DNS, to check for example using google DNS servers you could use something like:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 your-domain.tld
```

Also, give a try to https://intodns.com/ to check more details